# Check for invalid character

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello i am trying to figure out the following:

*Write the code to check whether a string given throughinput()contains only valid characters, but stop once you reach one invalid character. Do not forget that will print a little bit differently now, we want to see the valid part of the string too.*

Sample Input:
ATCGT ( but it can be other inputs)

Sample Output:
valid ATCGT

```
file = input()


for current_letter in file:
    if current_letter in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
        continue
    elif current_letter not in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
        break
print ('valid '+current_letter)
```

But my output is only : valid T

EDIT:

```
file = input()

correct_letters = []

for current_letter in file:
    if current_letter in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
        correct_letters.append(current_letter)
    else:
        break
print(f'valid {"".join(correct_letters)}')
```

This works also fine, thanks to L3viathan

Comment: also you are not reading the contents of the file... (not sure that is what you intend to do).

Comment: What's the output if the input is `ATCFA` or `FAIL`?

Comment: I'm not reading a file, just input. I must admit it looks a bit confusing calling the input 'file'

Comment: @L3viathan with ATCFA the output is valid ['A', 'T', 'C'] and with FAIL it is valid []

Comment: @MrButtonnn With your almost-working solution you only need to `print(f'valid {"".join(correct_letters)}')` and it should be how you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing what the instructions tell you. Here you give the last correct letter.
This will do the trick:

```
file = input()
correct_letters = ""
for current_letter in file:
    if current_letter in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
        correct_letters += current_letter
    else:
        break
print ('valid  '+ correct_letters)
```

Comment: He wants to break the loop if doesn't match, so after letters conditional ```ELSE:  break```

Comment: Thanks, I read the question the bad way, i'll edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time
However i still get Valid T as output, so there is still something not right

Comment: My bad again, this should have the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just always print `valid` , and then print characters one at a time, until you find a "bad" letter:

```
file = input()

print("valid ", end="")
for current_letter in file:
    if current_letter in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
        print(current_letter, end="")
    else:
        break
print("")
```